# Theming with React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, templates, themes, cakephp-2.x

I'm working on an old app with CakePHP 2 and I want to modernize it from scratch by making a new app based on Laravel and ReactJs, full API REST.
Actually I have an admin page to apply a specific theme to a store.
For example I have [www.store1.com](http://www.store1.com) and [www.store2.com](http://www.store2.com). When I enter the url [www.store1.com](http://www.store1.com) it loads the selected theme and templates, it loads default values if nothing is defined, using the theme system of CakePHP 2 with a structure like this :

- app
- sass

  - store1

    - ... scss files, compiled css goes to View/Themed/store1/webroot/css
- View

  - Themed

    - store1

      - View (specific templates)
      - webroot (specific css, fonts, etc ...)

I'm pretty new with Laravel and React, what I'm looking now is how achieve something similar with React :

- have a default theme (will use sass and bootstrap)
- load specific css and/or components depending on the chosen theme, load default if the specific css / component does not exist, theme is dedicated to an URL pointing to the same website.

Any help is welcomed, thanks

I've read many tutorials about react and themes, styled-components might be a hint, what i find is mostly theme switcher like light/dark theme but not sure that it's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `currentThemeLink` variable is used to keep track of the currently applied theme's CSS file. Before adding the new theme's CSS file, the code checks if a theme was previously loaded. If so, it removes the previous link tag from the document. This ensures that only one theme's CSS file is applied at a time, and the cleanup is handled properly when switching themes.

Remember to replace /path-to-themes/ with the actual path to your theme CSS files.

```
// Variable to store the reference to the currently loaded theme CSS file
let currentThemeLink = null;

function loadThemeCSS(themeName) {
  // Create a new link element for the selected theme
  const newThemeLink = document.createElement('link');
  newThemeLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
  newThemeLink.type = 'text/css';
  newThemeLink.href = `/path-to-themes/${themeName}.css`; // Replace with the actual path

  // If a theme was previously loaded, remove it before adding the new one
  if (currentThemeLink) {
    document.head.removeChild(currentThemeLink);
  }

  // Add the new theme's CSS file to the document
  document.head.appendChild(newThemeLink);

  // Update the reference to the current theme link
  currentThemeLink = newThemeLink;
}


// Example usage when the user selects a theme:
function handleThemeChange(themeName) {
  loadThemeCSS(themeName);
}

// Render your UI element for theme selection
<button onClick={() => handleThemeChange('theme-light')}>Light Theme</button>
<button onClick={() => handleThemeChange('theme-dark')}>Dark Theme</button>
```